# The record is created in database if transaction is aborted (MongoDB.Driver and .NETCore)

Tags: mongodb, transactions

Did anyone tried using transactions in .NetCore? I tried it and I can not get it to work properly.

My setup:

1. Mongo4 (3 node replica set)
2. Visual Studio 2017
3. MongoDB.Driver 2.7.0
4. .Net Core 2.0. Console application

I am following the instructions: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/

The problem is that new document is created in database every time (if I abort transaction, if I commit transaction,...)

I also tried using transactions directly on database and they work, I also tried it with NodeJS and they also work. Maybe there is a bug with driver, i do not know what I am doing wrong.

Code:

```
using System;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connString = "mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017";
            var client = new MongoClient(connString);

            using (var session = client.StartSession())
            {
                try
                {
                    RunTransactionWithRetry(UpdateEmployeeInfo, client, session);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    // do something with error
                    Console.WriteLine($"Non transient exception caught during transaction: ${exception.Message}.");
                }
            }

        }

        public static void RunTransactionWithRetry(Action<IMongoClient, IClientSessionHandle> txnFunc, IMongoClient client, IClientSessionHandle session)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    txnFunc(client, session); // performs transaction
                    break;
                }
                catch (MongoException exception)
                {
                    // if transient error, retry the whole transaction
                    if (exception.HasErrorLabel("TransientTransactionError"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("TransientTransactionError, retrying transaction.");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void CommitWithRetry(IClientSessionHandle session)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    session.CommitTransaction();
                    Console.WriteLine("Transaction committed.");
                    break;
                }
                catch (MongoException exception)
                {
                    // can retry commit
                    if (exception.HasErrorLabel("UnknownTransactionCommitResult"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("UnknwonTransactionCommiResult, retrying commit operation");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error during commit: {exception.Message}.");
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // updates two collections in a transaction
        public static void UpdateEmployeeInfo(IMongoClient client, IClientSessionHandle session)
        {
            var employeesCollection = client.GetDatabase("testdatabase").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("employees");
            var eventsCollection = client.GetDatabase("testdatabase").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("events");

            session.StartTransaction(new TransactionOptions(
                readConcern: ReadConcern.Snapshot,
                writeConcern: WriteConcern.WMajority));

            try
            {
                employeesCollection.UpdateOne(
                    Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("employee", 3),
                    Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("status", "Inactive"));
                eventsCollection.InsertOne(
                    new BsonDocument
                    {
                { "employee", 3 },
                { "status", new BsonDocument { { "new", "Inactive" }, { "old", "Active" } } }
                    });
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Caught exception during transaction, aborting: {exception.Message}.");
                session.AbortTransaction();
                throw;
            }

            //I WANT TO ABORT TRANSACTION - BUT THE RECORD "employee:3...." IS STILL IN DATABASE "events"
            session.AbortTransaction();
        }

        public static void UpdateEmployeeInfoWithTransactionRetry(IMongoClient client)
        {
            // start a session
            using (var session = client.StartSession())
            {
                try
                {
                    RunTransactionWithRetry(UpdateEmployeeInfo, client, session);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    // do something with error
                    Console.WriteLine($"Non transient exception caught during transaction: ${exception.Message}.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am also working with .net core ,even i coudn't resloving  session.CommitTransaction(); ,please help me how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pass in the `session` into the operations to include them into the transaction session. i.e. the [InsertOne](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollectionBase_1_InsertOne.htm) method accepts [IClientSessionHandle](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IClientSessionHandle.htm) as a first parameter.

Otherwise, the operations will act outside of the session as individual operations. Thus, the abort doesn't actually abort them.

Modifying your example:

```
var database = client.GetDatabase("testdatabase");
var employeesCollection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("employees");
var eventsCollection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("events");

session.StartTransaction(new TransactionOptions(
                             readConcern: ReadConcern.Snapshot,
                             writeConcern: WriteConcern.WMajority));

try
{
    employeesCollection.UpdateOne(
                session,
                Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("employee", 3),
                Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("status", "Inactive"));
    eventsCollection.InsertOne(
                session,
                new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "employee", 3 },
                    { "status", new BsonDocument { { "new", "Inactive" }, { "old", "Active" } } }
                });
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"Caught exception during transaction, aborting: {exception.Message}.");
     session.AbortTransaction();
     throw;
}

// OR session.CommitTransaction(); 
session.AbortTransaction();
```

The example above was written utilising [MongoDB .Net driver v2.7](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/), and MongoDB 4.0.

Please note that [MongoDB Multi-Document Transactions](https://www.mongodb.com/transactions) requires the collection namespace to exist.